# Magnetic dipole moment in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields, magnetic-moment

If we have a magnetic dipole moment $\vec{m}$ in a non-homogeneous magnetic field $\vec{B}$, how is torque $\vec{\tau} = \vec{m} \times \vec{B}$ related to  force $\vec{F}_{\text{dipole}} = -( \vec{m} \cdot \vec{\nabla}) \vec{B}$?

Answer (score 2):

Both equations come from the energy
$$U=-\mathbf m \cdot \mathbf B=-mB\cos\theta$$
If $\theta $ and the  magnetic moment magnitude are constants and $\mathbf B$ depends on the position, you have
$$\mathbf F=-\nabla U=-(\mathbf m \cdot \nabla )\mathbf B$$

If the magnetic field and is constant, you can easily see that the torque is
$$\boldsymbol \tau=\mathbf r\times \mathbf F= -\mathbf r\times \nabla U=-\mathbf r\times\left(\frac{m B}{r}\hat{\boldsymbol \theta}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\cos\theta\right)=mB\sin\theta=\mathbf {m}\times \mathbf B$$
If neither $\mathbf B $ or $\theta$ are constants, then you have more complicated expressions that include both.

Answer (score 0):

The force exerted on magnet 1 $\mathbf{m}_1$ (generating $\mathbf{B}_1$) by magnet 2 $\mathbf{m}_2$, separated by $\mathbf{r}$ is:
$$\mathbf{F} = \nabla (\mathbf{m}_2 \cdot \mathbf{B}_1). $$

The torque on magnet 1 by magnet 2 is defined in the usual way:
$$ \boldsymbol{\tau} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F}. $$

It turns out this generalises to:
$$ \boldsymbol{\tau} = \mathbf{m}_2 \times \mathbf{B}_1. $$

I could not find/produce a general proof for it, but it does work for different examples I tried.